# Pythonで１次元配列を昇順で並べ替え、その情報を他の配列に関連付けたい

Tags: python

li1を昇順に並べ替えた時にli2[i]も,最初のli1[i]とひも付けしたように並べ替えて2次元配列にして欲しいです。

```
li1=[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

li2=[1, 10,40,70,80, 2,11,41,71,81,3,12,42,72,82]
```

結果は以下の通りになると思います。

```
li1=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]


li2=[[1,10,2,11,3,12],[40,41,42],[70,72],[80,82]]
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6):

li1とli2を要素ごとに対応させたネストするリストを作ってgroupbyするのでどうでしょうか

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint as pp

li1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
li2 = [1, 10,40,70,80, 2,11,41,71,81,3,12,42,72,82]

merge = zip(li1, li2)
merge.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
group = groupby(merge, itemgetter(0))
li = [[item[1] for item in data] for (key, data) in group]

pp(li)
```

出力:

```
[[1, 10, 2, 11, 3, 12], [40, 41, 42], [70, 71, 72], [80, 81, 82]]
```

Comment: merge の生成は `merge = zip(li1, li2)` で簡潔に書けますね。

Comment: その通りです。内容を修正しました。

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> li2 = [[li2[i1] for i1 in range(len(li1)) if li1[i1] == idx] for idx in sorted(set(li1))]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。